# PHP - $_POST and $_SESSION trying to display multiple data

Tags: php, forms, session, post

I have a form that looks like this:

```
$dynamiclist = '<table align="center" width="60%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="8">
                        <tr height="20"></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="70%" valign="top" align="left"> <br />' . $name . ' <br /><br />$' . $price . '<br /><br />
                                 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="cart.php">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value=" ' . $id . '"/>';


    echo $dynamiclist;

$i=0;
foreach(explode(',', $keywords) as $keyword) {
    $keyword = trim($keyword);
    $chkname = "checkbox{$i}";
    $i = $i+1;
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chkboxes[]" value="'.$keyword.'" id="chk_'.$keyword.'" /><label for="chk_'.$keyword.'">'.$keyword.'</label>'."<br />\r\n";

     }
        echo '<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add to Order"/> </form> </td></tr></table>';
}
```

As you can see above I have a hidden field named "pid" pulling in the ID of an item from my database, and then I also have an input type checkbox with the name checkbox.

The problem i'm having is that I cannot display both of the data on the new page at the same time.

```
if(isset($_POST['chkboxes'])) {
  foreach($_POST['chkboxes'] as $chkbox) {
    echo 'Checkbox checked: '.$chkbox."<br />\r\n";
  }
}

if(isset($_POST['pid'])){
    $pid = $_POST['pid'];
    $wasfound = false;
    $i = 0;
        //if the cart session variable is not set or cart array is empty
    if(!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) or count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1){
        //Run if the cart is empty or not set
    $_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(1 => array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
    //establishing the cart_array variable in a session/multidimesional array -- database id assoc $pid from pid in form.
        }else {
            array_push($_SESSION["cart_array"], array("item_id"=> $pid, "quantity" => 1 ));
        }
        header("location: cart.php");
        exit();
    }//close if condition
```

I've tried removing `the $_POST['pid']`information and then the `$_POST ['chkboxes']` data is displayed as it should be. Any ideas? I'll pick the correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: I test your code and has a extra `}`.

Comment: Your code for me, works very well. Except for the extra `}` in the end of first file (form).

Comment: Edit your question, and post your `$_SESSION` code. Because I not understand where is the **session problem**.